# What is the probability of the second roll being a 3, in a 6 sided dice that has been rolled twice?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice, binomial-distribution

So, I was just wondering what would be the probability of rolling a $3$ in the second roll of a $6$ sided dice that has been rolled twice.

Is it just $\cfrac 16$ or do we still have to think about the past roll so $\cfrac 56 \cdot \cfrac 16$?

Comment: Each roll of a die is independent of any previous rolls, so the probability of rolling a $3$ is always $\frac16$ regardless of what has been rolled before (provided it is a fair $6$-sided die)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: Adding on what @ThomasGrubb said, you have touched on an important principle of probability. The gambler's fallacy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) shows that if two events are independent, the probability of a random event is always constant.

Comment: So i saw another example, stating find the probability of getting exactly two sixes when rolled three times...so would that be 1/6 *1/6 like this case or would you have to do 1/6*1/6*5/6?

Comment: @Sam None of them. It is $\frac16\times\frac16\times\frac56+\frac16\times\frac56\times\frac16+\frac56\times\frac16\times\frac16$.

Comment: $\frac56 \cdot \frac16$ would be the answer to the question: What is the probability that the first 3 occurs on the second roll?  But, as phrased, that is not, in fact, your question.